# Looking for a theory

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I have heard about a theory but don't know about its proof and name
The theory states that the roots of a symmetrical equation
$ax^2+bx+a=0$ would have roots $\alpha,\frac{1}{\alpha}$

Also the equation $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+bx+a$ have roots $\alpha,\frac{1}{\alpha},\beta,\frac{1}{\beta}$.

What is the name of this theory and proof i wanna know if it is also applicable in complex roots

Comment: I think you're looking for "reciprocal polynomial."  A polynomial with the properties you want is call "self-reciprocal."

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. Thank you